# Wget creates output file even when page does not exist

Tags: linux, bash, wget

**Is is possible to prevent Wget from making an output file when there is an error like 404.**

When I run

`wget -O my.html http://sdfsdfdsf.sdfds`

http://sdfsdfdsf.sdfds does not exist but Wget still creates my.html

---

I am making a bash script and want to make sure it stops if wget can't get a valid file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wget returns a non-zero response for non-200 replies (it seems).

This sample code worked for me with GNU wget:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget -O my.html http://sdfsdfdsf.sdfds

if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "ERROR"
fi
```

Here's more info about `$?` from [here](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt2.2.2.html).

> $?          the exit status of the last command executed is
>                 given as a decimal string.  When a command
>                 completes successfully, it returns the exit status
>                 of 0 (zero), otherwise it returns a non-zero exit
>                 status.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What does "$?" mean?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info about $?.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You could perhaps use curl(1) instead:

```
curl -s -f -o my.html http://sdfsdfdsf.sdfds
```